# Need to display a 12 hr clock

Tags: php, schedule, hour

I have thoroughly searched and I cannot find a solution to what I am trying to do. The scheduling time is in 24hr format. the software requires this 24 hour format to schedule email campaigns. However I need the page to "show" a 12 hour format with AM/PM options. How would I do this? I found this post: [Dropdown 24 hour option values and 12 hour display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10988939/dropdown-24-hour-option-values-and-12-hour-display) but it will not work for this style.

Can you give me an example of how I can achieve 3 drop downs (1-12 hour) (0, 15, 30, 45 min) (AM / PM)? Yet still have a 24 hour time on the backend for scheduling?

Here is a snippet of the code:

```
    <?php $SendTime = explode(':', $CampaignInformation['SendTime']); $SendTime = $SendTime[0]; ?>
                                    <?php $SendMinute = explode(':', $CampaignInformation['SendTime']); $SendMinute = $SendMinute[1]; ?>
                                    <label><?php InterfaceLanguage('Screen', '0834', false, '', false, true); ?></label>
                                    <select class="select" name="SendTimeHour">
                                        <option value="00" <?php echo set_select('SendTimeHour', '00', $SendTime == '00') ?>>0</option>
                                        <option value="01" <?php echo set_select('SendTimeHour', '01', $SendTime == '01') ?>>1</option>
                                        <option value="02" <?php echo set_select('SendTimeHour', '02', $SendTime == '02') ?>>2</option>
                                        <option value="03" <?php echo set_select('SendTimeHour', '03', $SendTime == '03') ?>>3</option>
                                        <option value="04" <?php echo set_select('SendTimeHour', '04', $SendTime == '04') ?>>4</option>
                                        <option value="05" <?php echo set_select('SendTimeHour', '05', $SendTime == '05') ?>>5</option>
                                        <option value="06" <?php echo set_select('SendTimeHour', '06', $SendTime == '06') ?>>6</option>
                                        <option value="07" <?php echo set_select('SendTimeHour', '07', $SendTime == '07') ?>>7</option>
                                        <option value="08" <?php echo set_select('SendTimeHour', '08', $SendTime == '08') ?>>8</option>
                                        <option value="09" <?php echo set_select('SendTimeHour', '09', $SendTime == '09') ?>>9</option>
                                        <option value="10" <?php echo set_select('SendTimeHour', '10', $SendTime == '10') ?>>10</option>
                                        <option value="11" <?php echo set_select('SendTimeHour', '11', $SendTime == '11') ?>>11</option>
                                        <option value="12" <?php echo set_select('SendTimeHour', '12', $SendTime == '12') ?>>12</option>
                                        <option value="13" <?php echo set_select('SendTimeHour', '13', $SendTime == '13') ?>>13</option>
                                        <option value="14" <?php echo set_select('SendTimeHour', '14', $SendTime == '14') ?>>14</option>
                                        <option value="15" <?php echo set_select('SendTimeHour', '15', $SendTime == '15') ?>>15</option>
                                        <option value="16" <?php echo set_select('SendTimeHour', '16', $SendTime == '16') ?>>16</option>
                                        <option value="17" <?php echo set_select('SendTimeHour', '17', $SendTime == '17') ?>>17</option>
                                        <option value="18" <?php echo set_select('SendTimeHour', '18', $SendTime == '18') ?>>18</option>
                                        <option value="19" <?php echo set_select('SendTimeHour', '19', $SendTime == '19') ?>>19</option>
                                        <option value="20" <?php echo set_select('SendTimeHour', '20', $SendTime == '20') ?>>20</option>
                                        <option value="21" <?php echo set_select('SendTimeHour', '21', $SendTime == '21') ?>>21</option>
                                        <option value="22" <?php echo set_select('SendTimeHour', '22', $SendTime == '22') ?>>22</option>
                                        <option value="23" <?php echo set_select('SendTimeHour', '23', $SendTime == '23') ?>>23</option>
                                    </select>
                                     : 
                                    <select class="select" name="SendTimeMinute">
                                        <option value="00" <?php echo set_select('SendTimeMinute', '00', $SendMinute == '00') ?>>00</option>
                                        <option value="15" <?php echo set_select('SendTimeMinute', '15', $SendMinute == '15') ?>>15</option>
                                        <option value="30" <?php echo set_select('SendTimeMinute', '30', $SendMinute == '30') ?>>30</option>
                                        <option value="45" <?php echo set_select('SendTimeMinute', '45', $SendMinute == '45') ?>>45</option>
                                    </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

So easy, just update the display on select box for hours and keep the rest same. Notice the AM / PM on select box display while the values for backend still remain the same.

```
<select class="select" name="SendTimeHour">
    <option value="00" <?php echo set_select('SendTimeHour', '00', $SendTime == '00') ?>>0 AM</option>
    <option value="01" <?php echo set_select('SendTimeHour', '01', $SendTime == '01') ?>>1 AM</option>
    <option value="02" <?php echo set_select('SendTimeHour', '02', $SendTime == '02') ?>>2 AM</option>
    <option value="03" <?php echo set_select('SendTimeHour', '03', $SendTime == '03') ?>>3 AM</option>
    <option value="04" <?php echo set_select('SendTimeHour', '04', $SendTime == '04') ?>>4 AM</option>
    <option value="05" <?php echo set_select('SendTimeHour', '05', $SendTime == '05') ?>>5 AM</option>
    <option value="06" <?php echo set_select('SendTimeHour', '06', $SendTime == '06') ?>>6 AM</option>
    <option value="07" <?php echo set_select('SendTimeHour', '07', $SendTime == '07') ?>>7 AM</option>
    <option value="08" <?php echo set_select('SendTimeHour', '08', $SendTime == '08') ?>>8 AM</option>
    <option value="09" <?php echo set_select('SendTimeHour', '09', $SendTime == '09') ?>>9 AM</option>
    <option value="10" <?php echo set_select('SendTimeHour', '10', $SendTime == '10') ?>>10 AM</option>
    <option value="11" <?php echo set_select('SendTimeHour', '11', $SendTime == '11') ?>>11 AM</option>
    <option value="12" <?php echo set_select('SendTimeHour', '12', $SendTime == '12') ?>>12 PM</option>
    <option value="13" <?php echo set_select('SendTimeHour', '13', $SendTime == '13') ?>>1 PM</option>
    <option value="14" <?php echo set_select('SendTimeHour', '14', $SendTime == '14') ?>>2 PM</option>
    <option value="15" <?php echo set_select('SendTimeHour', '15', $SendTime == '15') ?>>3 PM</option>
    <option value="16" <?php echo set_select('SendTimeHour', '16', $SendTime == '16') ?>>4 PM</option>
    <option value="17" <?php echo set_select('SendTimeHour', '17', $SendTime == '17') ?>>5 PM</option>
    <option value="18" <?php echo set_select('SendTimeHour', '18', $SendTime == '18') ?>>6 PM</option>
    <option value="19" <?php echo set_select('SendTimeHour', '19', $SendTime == '19') ?>>7 PM</option>
    <option value="20" <?php echo set_select('SendTimeHour', '20', $SendTime == '20') ?>>8 PM</option>
    <option value="21" <?php echo set_select('SendTimeHour', '21', $SendTime == '21') ?>>9 PM</option>
    <option value="22" <?php echo set_select('SendTimeHour', '22', $SendTime == '22') ?>>10 PM</option>
    <option value="23" <?php echo set_select('SendTimeHour', '23', $SendTime == '23') ?>>11 PM</option>
</select>
```

Comment: This is what I did in the meantime. What I am really trying to do is have 3 boxes. Hour Drop Down, Mins drop down, AMPM Drop Down. Is there a way I can do this? The hour box will show 1-12, and the new drop down will show AM/PM that user will select.